# How to select top 10 of the most rated movies from a database?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I'm quite new to MySQL and having a hard time running a complex query.
I have a two tables

**Movie table**

```
CREATE TABLE movies (movieid int(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
title varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
genres varchar(255) NOT NULL);
```

**Ratings table**

```
CREATE TABLE ratings (userid int(4) NOT NULL, movieid int(4) NOT NULL,
rating int(1) NOT NULL, timestamp int(10) NOT NULL ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ratings 
FOREIGN KEY(movieid) REFERENCES movies(movieid));
```

I want to get the top 10 most rated movie titles;
This is how far I have got with the query:

```
SELECT title 
FROM movie m
JOIN (
SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid) 
FROM ratings) 
ON m.movieid = r.movieid
LIMIT BY 10
```

I keep getting just `1` as a response.

Comment: should be ---> LIMIT 10

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `COUNT(movieid)`. It basically counts all the rows. making the ratings table side of the join just 1 row. What you want is to `GROUP BY` it by `movieid`, so that you get a separate rating count for each movieid.

try this:

```
SELECT title 
FROM movie m
JOIN (
SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid) 
FROM ratings GROUP BY movieid) 
ON m.movieid = r.movieid
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'm getting some `Every  derived table must have its own alias` error

Answer (score 1):

There is two missing points:

- grouping by the movie.movieid to get the count
- getting the MAX count not listing the count

Query (number of ratings):

```
SELECT movies.title, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ratings
WHERE ratings.movieid = movies.movieid ) AS raters
FROM movies ORDER BY raters DESC  LIMIT 10
```

Query (average rating )

```
SELECT movies.title, (SELECT SUM(ratings.rating)/COUNT(*) FROM ratings
WHERE ratings.movieid = movies.movieid ) AS raters
FROM movies ORDER BY raters DESC  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is this going to return the top 10?

Comment: top 10 movies which has the max number of rates, but if you want to sort according to the average rating you will have to change MAX(COUNT(*)) to MAX(SUM(ratings.rating)/COUNT(*))

Answer (score 1):

OUTER JOIN is not necessary here.

```
SELECT m.title, SUM(r.rating) / COUNT(m.movieid)
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN ratings r ON m.movieid = r.movieid
GROUP BY m.movieid
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```